# SPF Record for Multiple DKIMs (including MX)

Tags: dns, smtp, spf, dkim

I know very little about mail server administration. I'm piecing together user guides. I've bought a domain name, and [paid] Protonmail which allows using a custom domain. I've had this working for a while, but now I'm having trouble extending it for another DKIM record.

Objectives:

1. Send and receive email using Protonmail from the custom domain
2. Send-only email from a Postfix server I'm running

In order to send/receive email using Protonmail through my domain name, I've set up the following TXT records:

```
Host=@   protonmail-verification=e954fa...
```

```
Host=protonmail._domainkey    v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MGM0....
```

```
Host=@   v=spf1 include:_spf.protonmail.ch mx ~all
```

This has been working for months. Now I'd like to implement objective 2 (above). I created a DKIM key using `opendkim`:

```
sudo opendkim-genkey -b 8192 -h rsa-sha256 -r -v --subdomains -s postfix -d $(hostname --domain) && \
sudo sed -i 's/h=rsa-sha256/h=sha256/' postfix.txt
```

Then I've added the contents from `postfix.txt`, concatenating the long `p` string, to my DNS provider with another TXT record:

```
Host=[MY DOMAIN NAME]._domainkey      v=DKIM1; h=sha256; k=rsa; s=email; p=MEEij...
```

Where I *think* I'm struggling is with updating the `spf` record. How should it look? I *thought* it should be like so:

```
v=spf1 include:[MY DOMAIN NAME] include:_spf.protonmail.ch mx ~all
```

However, when testing sending an email from my Postfix server, some client servers reject the email, with the following log in my Postfix server:

```
E543D5E0003: host mail.tutanota.de[81.3.6.165] said: 450 4.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your reverse hostname, [MY POSTFIX SERVERS IP] (in reply to RCPT TO command)
```

I'm quite sure there is something wrong in my `spf` record. Are the arguments correct? And does the order matter? How can I use the Protonmail records for sending and receiving, but restrict my Postfix server to send-only? (does DNS even care about this directionality?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, let's start debugging this anyways ... (quite frankly, this is not a programming question so superuser would have been the better choice there, but I like that you wanna host your own mail :) )

Your SPF record should look like the following. Your own domain is not needed, cause the SPF record is saved in it's DNS records. Otherwise, that would (but won't) build a loop.

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.protonmail.ch mx ~all
```

The error itself you are seeing is related to the PTR lookup of your public IP, but could also be caused by the extra include and be a false positive here.

To make sure it's correct anyway, look it up manually:

On linux

```
dig -x <public ip of mail domain>
```

that will (should) print multiple lines, the one you're interested in:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.in-addr.arpa. 43200 IN    PTR     my-domain.com.
```

On windows:

```
nslookup <public ip of mail domain>
```

prints:

```
Server:  some.dns.server.com
Address:  XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

Name:    my-domain.com
Address:  <public ip of mail domain>
```

crucial here is the "my-domain.com." part - if that is not your mail domain, then your hosting provider will most likely give you a way to change the PTR somewhere.

Try this and then we will look futher into it if necessary, of course it's hard to debug without being able to lookup all the information ;)

Comment: I'm actually not seeing a `ANSWER SECTION` in my results, despite updating my SPF record to match your recommendation. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: To clarify, the SPF record and the PTR are two separate things. Changeing the SPF record won't affect the PTR entry, that will need to be changed on its own. The PTR entry is the reverse DNS lookup (IP to domain), it's located at the "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.in-addr.arpa." domain. This is not your own DNS server (if selfhosted) or with your domain provider - but with whoever owns the public IP you're using. This would be located at your server provider or when you have a static IP and the server at home at your internet provider. I will update my answer later to go more indepth, not giving up yet ;)

Comment: FWIW, I'm hosting the server on DigitalOcean. I've assigned a "floating IP" (static IP) from of their data centers to this host. This is the IP for which I've set an A Record in my DNS provider (Namecheap). However, from the DigitalOcean host itself (e.g., via SSH), the public IP assigned is different.

Using `dig -x {public IP}` against either the floating IP or the static assigned IP, has similar result. The only row that DOES NOT begin with a semicolon is like: `xxx.yyy.zzzin-addr.arpa. 1800 IN SOA ns1.digitalocean.com. hostmaster.xxx.yyy.zzz.in-addr.arpa.    ....`

Comment: Would be happy to take this into chat, but I actually can't figure out how in SO...

I agree, this was probably not the best forum for this question. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Oh oh, that's a problem. DigitalOcean's "floating" IP's do not come with the capability to set a PTR on them. There is a request for this for a long time and it seems they won't add this anytime soon sources: [request at Digital Ocean](https://ideas.digitalocean.com/ideas/DO-I-1023) and [others having the same problem](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-do-i-set-the-ptr-for-a-floating-ip)

Comment: For the chat, that's here: [StackExchange Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com) or [StackOverflow Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/). You can go to a users profile and invite them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214878/discussion-between-ch-pub-and-oxados).